# SonarQube suggest a!==a instead of a===NaN

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, nan

There is a SonarQube JavaScript Rule ([`javascript:S2688`](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=javascript%3AS2688)) which says that the use of `a === NaN` is a bug because it's always `false`.

I agree with that but I think to use `a !== a` instead (this is suggested by SonarQube) is a very bad idea.
It's a funny JavaScript fact but certainly not a "best practice".

What about `Number.isNaN(a)`? Why is this not the suggested solution? Are there any differences or problems which I've missed?

Comment: Thank you @nnnnnn. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> the use of `a === NaN` is a bug because it's always `false`.

This *behaviour* is not a bug, because it is how `NaN` has been defined to work. But if you actually used `a === NaN` in a program then *that* would be a bug because of the always-`false` result.

> `a !== a` instead ... is a very bad idea. It's a funny JavaScript fact but certainly not a "best practice".

I disagree with your "certainly". Due to problems with the original global `isNaN()` function (which I'll explain in a moment), `a !== a` was, historically the best way to test for [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). So in fact it is a very common practice to use that technique, and I would expect the vast majority of experienced JavaScript developers to be familiar with it.

`NaN` *is* the only value that tests as not equal to itself.

> What about `isNaN(a)`? Why is this not the suggested solution? Are there any differences or problems which I've missed?

The original, global [`isNaN()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) *doesn't actually test whether its argument is `NaN`.* Nor does it test if its argument is some other non-numeric value. What it does is first try to convert its argument to a number and then test if the result of that conversion is equal to `NaN`.  This implicit conversion means that, e.g., `isNaN("test")` returns `true` even though a string is not equal to the value `NaN`. And `isNaN("")` returns `false` because an empty string can be coerced to `0`. If that behaviour is what you're looking for then yes, use `isNaN()`.

So all of that is why ECMAScript 6/2015 introduced a new function, [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN), which does test *specifically* for the value `NaN`, giving an equivalent result to the old-school `a !== a`.

As suggested in the comments, for older browsers (basically old IE) that don't support `Number.isNaN()`, if you want something clearer than `a !== a` and don't mind longer code you can do this:

```
typeof a == "number" && isNaN(a)
```

...which is one of the two [`Number.isNaN()` polyfills suggested by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN#Polyfill). (The other just uses `a !== a`.)

Comment: `typeof a == "number" && isNaN(a)` might be a clearer alternative. There are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Also note `Number.isNaN(a)` being new means it isn't supported in all browsers (ex: IE). While `a !== a` works in any browser.